# How to make AnchorPane rounded inside another AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

As the title says I have created a root AnchorPane in which two AnchorPanes are placed the upper AnchorPane somehow gets rounded but in case of lower one, the upper side is rounded whereas the lower side remains edged.

> Java Code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        try 
        {
            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("load.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            scene.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            primaryStage.show();

            root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
            {
                public void handle(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    xOffset = e.getSceneX();
                    yOffset = e.getSceneY();

                }
            });

            root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
            {
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    primaryStage.setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                    primaryStage.setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Most of the Designing part is done using Scene Builder in fxml file

> FXML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="452.0" prefWidth="362.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-border-radius: 30;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="362.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3D4956; -fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-border-radius: 30;" />
      <AnchorPane fx:id="pg1" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="373.0" prefWidth="362.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3D4956; -fx-background-radius: 30;" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image: Project Image]

Comment: The two `AnchorPane`s are differently styled (the one that has an `fx:id` lacks the style `-fx-border-radius: 30;`... Could be a reason, but another one might be invisible bottom part, are you sure it is entirely visible (does not exceed the lower border of its parent)?

Comment: I have used -fx-border-radius : 30 it still shows the same and AnchorPane Doesn't exceed its Parent AnchorPane

Comment: completely unrelated: please don't use blockquote tags for highlighting, they are for .. guess .. quotes :)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow, therefore I mistakenly used it without knowing it's actual purpose

Comment: you can edit your question and remove them :)

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me (until I resize the window to make the scene smaller than the preferred size of the root). Note that you haven't produced a responsive layout there.

If you want to wrap everything in an `AnchorPane`, replace `layoutY="80.0"` with `AnchorPane.topAnchor="80" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0"` and the bottom `AnchorPane` will shrink/grow when resizing the window vertically.

Note though that there is a simpler way to produce this kind of layout (the responsive version) that using `AnchorPane`: Just use a `VBox`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:id="root" spacing="10" prefHeight="452.0" prefWidth="362.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-border-radius: 30;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="70.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3D4956; -fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-border-radius: 30;" />
      <AnchorPane fx:id="pg1" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" style="-fx-background-color: #3D4956; -fx-background-radius: 30;" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

`VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"` results in the second `AnchorPane` being grown to the space remaining in the `VBox`.